# What is the domain of the plus operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, addition

I'm looking at [the MDN documentation of the plus (`a + b`) operator in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators). It seems like the operator is defined on all combinations of `number`, `string`, and `bool` arguments. From experimentation, it is also defined on arrays, objects, null, closures ...

The question: **is there any combination of values for which the plus operator is *not* defined, i.e. those arguments are not in the domain of the `+` function?** (Where operationally, "not defined" basically means an exception will be thrown or the program will halt with an error if `+` is applied to those arguments.)

Bonus points for answering the equivalent question for the other "arithmetic operators" (which seem to do far more than arithmetic ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` operator is only defined for numbers (addition) and strings (concatenation).

However, it coerces its arguments to number or string. Full details in the spec, [§11.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1). Basically: Processing `+` does a "to primitive" on the operands, which means it then ends up with numbers, strings, booleans, nulls, or undefineds. If either operand, after coercion to primitive, is a string, it then coerces the other to string and does concatenation; otherwise, it coerces both to number and does addition.

The result of "to primitive" on objects depends on the object, but most objects end up coercing to string or number.

The only objects that can't be coerced to primitives are objects lacking both a `toString` and a `valueOf`*; in that case, [§8.12.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) tells us that a `TypeError` is thrown. In practice, the only objects that won't have `toString` and `valueOf` are ones that A) Don't have their own copy of them, **and** B) Have no prototype or a prototype chain that doesn't include `Object.prototype`. For example, an object created by `Object.create(null)` (which has no prototype).

So no, there's no combination of values for which `+` is *undefined* but there is an edge case where it will throw a `TypeError`:

1. *(Normal case)* Both operands can coerced to a primitive, and any primitive can be coerced to a string or a number (the resulting number may, of course, be `NaN`), and so we get a resulting value, or
2. *(Edge case)* One of the two operands can't be converted to primitive, in which case we get a `TypeError`

---

* Okay, they don't have to be missing: If the object has `toString` but `toString` returns a non-primitive, then we get the `TypeError` if the object doesn't have `valueOf` or the object has `valueOf`, but `valueOf` also returns a non-primitive. In practice, `toString` and `valueOf` are supposed to return primitives.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how you answered this so quickly and comprehensively! It took me longer just to read your answer than it took you to read my question and write your response! Anyway, that's cool, thanks. Good to know about `Object.create(null)` -- that's quite an edge case.